# declaring the fragment in the xml layout file and using FragmentTransaction.replace

Tags: android, xml, fragment

if i declare a fragment in the xml layout file, does that mean i can not use any of the fragmentTransaction methods?

i understand that both add and remove methods cannot be used, however with replace, your are not removing the fragment.

i am trying to figure out if this is the reason for my errors.

```
 FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
     FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
     fragmentTransaction.remove(youTubePlayerFragment);
     fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `fragmentTransaction`, but not `.remove()` or `.replace()` as you can't remove or replace a fragment that you added statically inside your `XML` file.
Instead you can `.hide()` and `.show()` the added fragment in the `XML` file to manipulate it existence on screen.